JavaFX RuntimeException: Illegal texture dimensions (2147483647x37)
I am encountering a similar issue as JDK-8177629 with JavaFX 21 on Intel Iris Xe Graphics; it seems like this issue is also present in Javafx20 as commented by  Andy Goryachev
We are in progress of migrating from Javafx11 to Javafx21
Here is the stack trace:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Illegal texture dimensions (2147483647x37)
    at com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DResourceFactory.createRTTexture(D3DResourceFactory.java:330)
    at com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DResourceFactory.createRTTexture(D3DResourceFactory.java:63)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.UploadingPainter.run(UploadingPainter.java:125)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:572)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:358)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java:58)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:126)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)

System Info:

OS: [Windows]
GPU: Intel Iris Xe Graphics
Driver Version: 31.0.101.4953
JVM Options: Tried -Dprism.order=sw and -Dprism.forceGPU=false as workarounds, which mitigated the issue.

This issue persists across multiple environments and appears related to large texture allocations.

2147483647 = 0x7FFFFFFF = Integer.MAX_VALUE.

The error occurs in com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DResourceFactory.  That is a Direct3D specific implementation (the class doesn't even exist on my Mac JavaFX installation).  If you run the code using only software order for rendering, then the Direct3D hardware renderer would not be used. If you want additional assistance, you could provide a [mcve], as well as the stack trace provided when you use the software rendering switch (which should not include the D3DResourceFactory class).

Often, texture issues can be caused by application code updating the active scene graph from a non-JavaFX thread, generating a race condition with the JavaFX processing and rendering threads.

Without code this is going to be very hard to answer. It seems like a JavaFX bug (possibly aggravated or exposed by a bug/behaviour change in the graphics driver), and it seems distinct from the JDK bug you linked (different error, different stack trace). I’d file it as a JavaFX bug and include as much information as you can for reproduction (ideally, a [mre]). If it’s specific to Intel Xe and/or that specific driver version, it might be worth a report to Intel too.
